# Exporting Database from Access 2007 to Sql 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, export, ms-access-2007

Fellow Developers I have been working on creating a Database with SQL Server 2005, now I finished that step, its a huge and massive one. Now the company wants me to export their data from their Access 2007 db to this sql 2005 database I created.

I know that I will be using field mapping, but is it actually possible to do that ?

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Have you considered the [upsizing wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-HA010275537.aspx) and once its in SQL server moving the data as you'd like

Comment: @ConradFrix That would be good solution provided that both databases are identical. If the databases are identical I can post a script that I created that will build the INSERT statements for you. You would need to import the Access data into the SQL Server instance or create a linked server first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major portion of my job is converting data from one data source into another. I am actually doing a Filemaker Pro to SQL Server conversion right now. I have tried some of these Automatic solutions and they are hit or miss depending upon the complexity of the data involved. Usually, I do it by mostly by hand writing scripts (I do automate some of the scripts using a VB6 application I created many years ago).

I have found that doing the scripts by hand always produces the best conversions.

Comment: thnx for your replies, I'm feeling somehow stuck and down at this point since I'm on deadline! I will look into getting scripts. To be honest never got this far!

Comment: No worries, if the two databases are identical then you maybe better off using SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

[This fellow](https://cfpayne.wordpress.com/2006/07/23/how-to-import-microsoft-access-into-sql-server-2005/) describes how he did it. There is a tool called "**SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access**" that you can download from Microsoft. The blog also has a Word document that you can download for a step-by-step description of what to do.

You can download SSMA [here](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=959) and possibly just figure out how to do it without searching further.

Comment: Thanks, this sound promising! When I googled this was my only choice, that is why I posted here! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the import.  Try using SQL's import wizard first.  If that's too limited, you may need to create an SSIS package.

Comment: Thanks My friend, I will look into SSIS. its my first time to hear about this. I feel so novice at this point! Thanks again!